# How do I apply AIC to test out how many eigenvalues are different from 1 in a diagonalised covariance matrix?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, aic, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

Given that we have $x_1$,...,$x_n$ with dimensions $p * 1$ each, and $X_i$ ~ N(0,Σ), we form the diagonalised covariance matrix Σ such that the first K eigenvalues are unknown and the remaining $n-K$ eigenvalues are all 1s. We can take for example P = 50 , n = 100. $\frac{P}{n}$ → c > 0. P is the dimension and n is the sample size.

How do we make use of AIC to test how many eigenvalues are different from 1 ?